# npm package not working in custom bash script during pre-commit hook

Tags: bash, git, shell, npm, githooks

I want to run lint-staged in my custom pre-commit hook.
I have the .githooks in the root of my project. I symlink them and hooks work, they get invoked correctly. Then server folder is also at the same level. And inside server I have my node_modules and package.json
pre-commit hook get invoked, but lint-staged doesn't throw any error and my script is successfully executed. But I am sure that staged file has errors, because lint-staged throws error if I directly call it in my terminal.

**.githooks/pre-commit**

```
    #!/bin/bash
    script_path=$(readlink -f "$0")
    hooks_dir=$(dirname "$script_path")
    root_dir=$(dirname "$hooks_dir")
    echo "Running pre-commit"
    cd "${root_dir}/server" && npx lint-staged
```

Answer (score 1):

Git hooks should be under `.git/hooks`, not `.githooks`.

Comment: they are. 
I symlink them with my custom directory in order to store them in remote as well.